# Exchange Admin Archiving for Legal Purposes

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I have a new Exchange server and a few domains setup, all seems to be working OK.
One of my clients is asking how the Archiving works as of now as they need to keep all email communications for the last 7 years for legal purposes.  What is the simplest way to meet this requirement in Exchange?

Thanks for any tips,

Answer (score 2):

Under Exchange 2013, you'll want to leverage the [Litigation Hold and In-Place Hold](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/12/11/litigation-hold-and-in-place-hold-in-exchange-2013-and-exchange-online.aspx) features (*and possibly journaling*) to meet the retention requirements of your organization.

Comment: Looks like the recommend In place hold for 2013 - however when i try to turn it on I get a 401 error!